# Spark Job Reading Parquet Data

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I have a spark job which reads a parquet data files .
Each Parquet file has block size of 32 MB and 13 Blocks .

I started the spark shell with 2 executor and 10 cores , which means 20 cores are available .
The job reads 10 parquet files and executes a count operation .

I assumed that since there are 13 blocks/file (10*13=130) , 130 tasks should run on that stage . But I can only see 36 tasks getting executed in that stage.
Also while reading the 10 files I can only see 20 Tasks doing the job . As there are 130 blocks , won't 130 tasks be spawned with each task reading a block .
Is there anything wrong in my understanding .

The commands I am Running are as below :
Spark Shell Command :

```
spark-shell --master yarn-client --num-executors 2 --executor-cores 10 --executor-memory 420G --driver-memory 2g --conf spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=4096
```

Scala Code :

```
***> val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc) val parqfile

> =sqlContext.read.parquet("location.parquet")
> 
> parqfile.registerTempTable("temptable")
> 
> val p1 =sqlContext.sql("select count(*) from temptable") 
> val p2=p1.show(100, false)
```

Comment: 20 cores means 20 tasks that can be executed in parallel. Unfortunately I'm not sure how the number of tasks is generated in this case.

Comment: does `spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled` is set to `ture` ?

Comment: @Harisyam: any update ???

Comment: Yes . It is set as true . But still the the tasks are not proportional to the blocks / split .